# perl forking implementation for huge number of file parsing

Tags: perl, fork

I have implemented the concept for forking for parsing of the huge file as per below but seems it not correct.
Few issue i am facing with the code some of the variable are not getting accessed.

```
    #ALL the variable in Complete CAPS are global variable
    TLog("MSG",1,"Parent process $$");
    TLog("MSG",4,"Creating child process for $$");
    my $MAX_FORK       = 2;
    my $forkCount      = 0;
    my $processCounter = 0;
    my @childId   = ();

    foreach my $fileNameFasta (@{$ref_array_file}) {

        my $pid = fork();


        if ( $pid ) {

            TLog("MSG",1,"child process created : $pid");
            push @childId,$pid;

            $forkCount++;
        }
        elsif ( $pid == 0 ) {

            my $outputFile = $STAT_FILE;
            my $pidLocal   = $childId[$processCounter]; #Use of unintialized variable

            $outputFile =~s/\d{1,}\.txt$/$pidLocal\.txt/og; #hence naming of all ouput file are same                
            TLog("MSG",1,"For $pidLocal Creating output file for stat : $outputFile");

            open my $outputfh,'>',$outputFile;
            GenerateTupleCountFile($outputfh,$fileNameFasta);    
            close  $outputfh;


            TLog("MSG",5,"Calculation completed for $pidLocal");
            TLog("MSG",5,"Plz check the $outputFile");
            $processCounter++;

            exit(0);

        }

        if ( $forkCount >= $MAX_FORK ) {
            foreach (@childId) {
                   my $tmp = waitpid($_, 0);
                   TLog("MSG",5,"Process completed for with pid $tmp");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide me right direction , if I am wronge.

Comment: I will recommend to use the Parallel::ForkManager module which handles most of the process bookkeeping for you above code. As I understand you code new children will only be started when all children are done and the code you have shown will only wait for the last iteration if and only if there are an even number of files to process. Parallel::ForkManager will handled both cases better. You still need to take Jonathan Lefflers answer into account, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the fork has taken place, the parent and child are autonomous.

You never set anything in the `@childID` array until after the `fork`, by which time it is too late for the child to know what's written in there for it.  You need to use `getpid()` in the child, or the magic variable — `$$`, or (if you've used [`use English '-no_match_vars';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) `$PID` or `$PROCESS_ID`.  The parent never increments `$processCounter`.

Similarly, the child increments its copy of `$processCounter`, but that cannot affect the variable in the parent.